# How to pass a variable content to the client side?

Tags: javascript, express

I'm working with express js. I want to pass the content of the variable "resultat" to the client side and put it into a javascript variable to be used in a ejs page.
this code is in app.js

```
var fs = require('fs');// File System Module
var xml2js = require('xml2js'); // XML2JS Module
var parser = new xml2js.Parser(); // Creating XML to JSON parser object
// Reading and Parsing the file 
fs.readFile( 'views/xmlfile.xml', function(err, data) {
    parser.parseString(data, function (err, resultat) {
        console.log(resultat);
        console.log('Done');
    });
});
```

[the content of the variable "resultat" is shown in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4pW7.png)

Comment: Where's your express server?

Comment: can u give me your mail to solve the problem

Comment: No, just [edit] your question to include the details

Answer (score 0):

You could use this (client-side):

```
<script>
  var myVar = <%- JSON.stringify(myVar) %>;
</script>
```

You could also get EJS to render a .js file

In router file you will get res object.

```
fs.readFile( 'views/xmlfile.xml', function(err, data) {
parser.parseString(data, function (err, resultat) {
    console.log(resultat);
    console.log('Done');
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
   res.render('testPage', { myVar : resultat : ... });
    });
});
```